# how to assign values to a instance in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a class without the constructor.

```
export class UserInfo {
  public userName: string = '';
  public belongTo: string = '';
}
```

I can assign it after creating an instance of the class.

```
let u:UserInfo = new UserInfo();
u.userName = 'name';
u.belongTo = 'A';
```

But I want to assign it when creating the instance, probably like:

```
let u:UserInfo = {userName:name, belongTo:A};
let u:UserInfo = new UserInfo(){userName:name, belongTo:A};
let u:UserInfo = <UserInfo>{userName:name, belongTo:A};
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try Object.assign()

Answer (score 1):

Try below methods

Method 1:
class with constructor

```
class A {
int a;

constructor(int a){
this.a=a;
}    

}
//Object creation
let x:A=new A(1);
```

Method 2:Object Assignment

```
Object.assign(new A(),{a:1})
```

Comment: Where can I find the documentation about `Object.assign` online? I found it's from `typescript/lib`

Comment: assign is a JavaScript function inside Object https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can use this syntax just like in C# (Correct me if i'm wrong):

```
let u:UserInfo = new UserInfo(){userName:name, belongTo:A};
```

The closest thing to achieve what you want would be:

```
class UserInfo {
    constructor(private userName: string, private belongTo: string) {
    }
}
```

And the initialization would be:

```
let u:UserInfo = new UserInfo(name, A);
```

I was seeing [this](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2013/04/stop-manually-assigning-typescript-constructor-parameters/) as the reference.